# I am having trouble installing NASM on my MacBook Pro

Tags: nasm

I read all the post in google but still I cannot find any ways to install NASM on my MacBook Pro. I install OS X mountain Lion and installed command line from Xcode still I cannot install NASM on my Mac. Pls bring me to step to step set up on Mac. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What did you try and what error did you encounter?

Comment: I downloaded NASM but I find no files to install and run it. I tried few times but still the same result.

Comment: What's the link to what you downloaded? In some cases, they're source packages that have to be compiled.

Comment: Looks like I am missing something that I don't know.

Comment: I use this site. http://www.neuraladvance.com/compiling-and-installing-nasm-on-mac-os-x.html

Comment: From it I downloaded NASM Mac version and I unzipped it I can open files but nothing to install..

Comment: The instructions on that site say that after you download and unzip it, you have to go to the top folder of what you unzipped and enter `./configure` etc. There are a few steps you have to go through to compile the code before you can actually instal the `nasm` command. It has to be built first.

Comment: Oh i have to do that. There are bunch of files in that folder. I will try that thanks a lot..

Comment: Yes, there will be many files. Just try to step through exactly what they say to do on that site you pointed to.

Comment: i followed exact steps. still, showing errors like this. help me.dereck-MacBook-Pro:~ gyalink$ cd /Users/gyalink/Downloads/nasm-2.09.10 
Penpa-Gyaltsens-MacBook-Pro:nasm-2.09.10 pen_gyalink$ ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
dereck-MacBook-Pro:nasm-2.09.10 gyalink$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
dereck-MacBook-Pro:nasm-2.09.10 gyalink$ sudo make install
Password:
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
Penpa-Gyaltsens-MacBook-Pro:nasm-2.09.10 pen_gyalink$ ......(I cannot go farther than this pls advice me.)

Comment: After you change to `/Users/gyalink/Downloads/nasm-2.09.10` and you do `ls`, what do you see? You should put your information in your question text properly formatted rather than in the comments. Otherwise they are very hard to read.

Comment: ./configure is not working. it says -bash no such file or directory found. i spent two days figuring out this but still i couldn't..

Comment: See my previous comment.